# What is "this" inside the event .on('click', 'class', function () {})

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, event-delegation

I try to have access to the row i clicked to add or remove a class, but it seems like i misinterpreted the value of `this`. Isn't it supose to be the DOM where the event go called (in this case, the `<li>`)? Here is my code:

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).on('click', '.ToDownload', function() 
        {
            if($(this).className.lastIndexOf("isSelected") != -1)
            {
                $(this).addClass("isSelected");
                $(this).css('border', '2px solid #000099')
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).removeClass("isSelected");
                $(this).css('border', 'none')
            }
        });
```

**HTML**

```
<li id="addedDownloadFileRow" class="fitting ToDownload">
    <a href="#">
        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">test1</div>
            <div class="ui-block-b">test2</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

In fact, i thought i could use the property `className` to find if my row is already selected, but it seems like `this` isnt the DOM of the `<li>` tag. Any information or a way to see what `this` really is would be appreciated.

P.S. The class "fitting" is only used for some css purpose.

Comment: What makes you think it would be the `<li>` and not the `<div>` inside?

Comment: @azium presumably because of the `'.ToDownload'` in the call to `on()`

Comment: And `console.log(this)` or `console.dir(this)` will pretty much tell you what you want.

Comment: I would use `if($(this).is(".isSelected"))` to check if the element is selected instead

Comment: "this" is referring to the current element and the basic syntax is: `$(selector).action()`

Comment: @CupawnTae oh gosh, thanks I skimmed over that somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is a `DOM Element`, `$(this)` is a jQuery object

Full working code is in http://jsfiddle.net/tomi77/xgv8q9md/

Comment: Thanks alot! This short and clear answer was exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Chrome (not sure whether this works in Firefox), you can log the value of `this` to the console.

If it is a jQuery object, it might not be clear to see which element it refers to, however it's straightforward to get the underlying element out.

```
console.log(this[0]);
```

This will give you a minimal representation of the element itself and if you hover over it, you'll see the element highlighted in the web view itself.

[image]

This lets you see *exactly* which element it refers to. As mentioned in the comments, you can also log the direct object form of the element to the console with `console.dir(element)`.

Comment: `console.dir(this[0])` on elements gives you more information about the node object which is useful.